# Solving an equation with the Brent method

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages

How do I write correct code to use the Brent method to solve an equation? My code is

```
p[R_] := R/(1 + R); q[R_] := 1/(1 + R);
a = 0.001; t = 100;
e = 0.491;
al[g_] := ArcCos[(a * Cos[q[t] * Sinh[g]/(g/a - p[t])] - Cosh[g])];
FindRoot[
     al[x] - 2 * Pi * e == a * Sin[al[x]]/(Cosh[x] + Cos[al[x]]),
     {x, 0, 4},
     Method -> "Brent"
]
```

I get the error message

> FindRoot::bbrac: Method -> Brent is only applicable to univariate real functions and requires two real starting values that bracket the root.

Comment: Try `Plot[{al[x] - 2*Pi*e, a*Sin[al[x]]/(Cosh[x] + Cos[al[x]])}, {x, 0, 4},
  PlotRange -> All]`...

Comment: Thanks but I need something different. How to write the script correctly.

Comment: Look at where the lines cross in the plot.  The upper limit of your bracket is two orders of magnitude above that point (and the values at higher `x` are tending to ±infinity) so try reducing the bracket, e.g. `{x,0,0.04}`.

Comment: Ah, ok. That was working. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

Your functions return complex values, hence the error message:

```
{al[x] - 2*Pi*e, a*Sin[al[x]]/(Cosh[x] + Cos[al[x]])} /. x -> 4
```

> ```
> {0.05654866776461631` - 3.9999633557579153` I, 0.` + 27.288916588244273` I}
> ```

You should restrict the range to the real domain:

```
FindRoot[al[x] - 2*Pi*e == a*Sin[al[x]]/(Cosh[x] + Cos[al[x]]), {x, 0, .04}, 
 Method -> "Brent"]
```

> ```
> {x -> 0.03464662602138138`}
> ```